# Escape sequence for ? in c++

Tags: c++, string, escaping, trigraphs

I was looking at the escape sequences for characters in strings in c++ and I noticed there is an escape sequence for a question mark.  Can someone tell me why this is?  It just seems a little odd and I can't figure out what ? does in a string.  Thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's to keep a question mark from getting misinterpreted as part of a [trigraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs).

For example, in

```
"What??!"
```

The "??! would be interpreted as the `|` character.  So, you have to escape the question marks as follows:

```
"What\?\?!"
```

Example complements of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt0y4awe%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: By default, gcc disables the interpretation of trigraphs, unless they're explicitly enabled with `-trigraphs`, `-ansi`, or some of the `-std=xxx` options.  `-Wtrigraphs` (enabled by `-Wall`) also enables warnings for trigraph sequences.

Comment: All about trigraphs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234582/purpose-of-trigraph-sequences-in-c/1234618#1234618

Comment: You just ignore the existence of trigraphs... until they bite you in the ass.

Comment: @Mattihieu - that's pretty much what I do and it's really not a problem. The tradeoff of once every 7 or 8 years relearning why I hate trigraphs is an acceptable cost to not worrying about them at any other time. But, GCC is right to disable them by default (I think).

Comment: An alternate way of writing the indicated string would be `"What?""?!"` (since the compiler will concatenate the literals after the preprocessor has looked for (and not found) trigraph sequences.  Breaking string literals can also be useful when using numeric escapes that are followed by digits [e.g. if one wanted `"Hello"` followed by a zero byte followed by a digit 3', `"Hello\0""3"`.  Incidentally for `?` one could either use `\x3F` followed by something other than a hex digit, or `\077`.