# Use of '??=', '??<' and '??>' in c

Tags: c, trigraphs

I was going through few interview questions and I came across example as below. I tried the example for simple input/output and also for some logic and it works without any problems.

```
??=include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
??<
    printf("Hello");
    // Other code lines here
    return 0;
??>
```

To my surprise, this worked without any compilation issue and output was as required.

What is the significance of '??=', '??<' and '??>' here ?

Comment: @user3121023 Thanks for the comment. I got the confusion cleared after I searched for trigraphs.

Comment: Trigraphs are provided to allow a minimal character set. Aside: early keyboards had a `#` key or a `£` key but not both, which I guess led to some people referring to the `#` hash symbol as a "pound". Happy that it is reverting as in "hash-tag" not "pound-tag".

Comment: @WeatherVane Yeah I just read these were used by old keyboards that did not contain complete key set used by C/C++. Not sure why this ended up in examples for interview. Such kind of keyboards can rarely be found now.

Comment: I've never seen trigraphs used in the wild. Usually, programmers would just use whatever character glyphs their local 7-bit character set mapped to the corresponding ASCII codes, for example replacing `#` with `£` in the UK, or replacing `\ ` with `¥` in Japan.

Comment: @WeatherVane "pound sign" is because the [# character is literally used to represent "pounds as a unit of weight or mass"](https://www.lexico.com/definition/pound_sign)

Comment: @AndrewHenle oh, I didn't know that US usage. I seem to remember an old printer which had a switch setting to determine what was printed for `0x23`, because those keyboards didn't use a different code for `#` and `£`. It was just the key-top.

Comment: more duplicates: [What does the ??!??! operator do in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7825055/995714), [Escape sequence for ? in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1586834/995714), [Cryptic line “??!??!” in legacy code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17718286/995714), [What is the meaning of these strange question marks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23825603/995714), [What is the meaning of `???-` in C++ code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16662276/995714)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***What is the significance of '??=', '??<' and '??>' here ?***

`??=` will be replaced with `#`,

`??<` will be replaced with `{`,

`??>` will be replaced with `}`,

by the preprocessor. These are called trigraphs.  There are 9 trigraphs in total; the others are:

`??(` will be replaced with `[`,

`??)` will be replaced with `]`,

`??/` will be replaced with `\`,

`??'` will be replaced with `^`,

`??!` will be replaced with `|`,

`??-` will be replaced with `~`.

Trigraphs are processed very early in the translation process, before the source code is tokenized.  They can affect comments and strings and character literals.