# Why does GCC emit a warning when using trigraphs, but not when using digraphs?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-warnings, digraphs, trigraphs

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  ??< puts("Hello Folks!"); ??>
}
```

The above program, when compiled with GCC 4.8.1 with `-Wall` and `-std=c11`, gives the following warning:

```
source_file.c: In function ‘main’:
source_file.c:8:5: warning: trigraph ??< converted to { [-Wtrigraphs]
     ??< puts("Hello Folks!"); ??>
 ^
source_file.c:8:30: warning: trigraph ??> converted to } [-Wtrigraphs]
```

But when I change the body of `main` to:

```
<% puts("Hello Folks!"); %>
```

no warnings are thrown.

So, **Why does the compiler warn me when using trigraphs, but not when using digraphs?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are trigraphs generating errors in modern C++ compilers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13619504/why-are-trigraphs-generating-errors-in-modern-c-compilers)

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I think the answers there contain all the information that could be given in an answer to this question, even if a new version (or different frontend?) of gcc downgraded its handling of trigraphs to a warning.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour The linked question still says gcc generates *warnings* and the errors are from *Turbo C*. So I don't think anything has changed since.

Comment: @BlueMoon I just realized the reason why the behavior appears different is that now almost everyone is using `-std=xxx` which means that `gcc` will automatically turn on trigraphs. So perhaps I agree this is a duplicate.

Comment: the trigraph and digraph were from the days when many/most keyboards did not have the appropriate keys.   Today, all that is obsolete and should not be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [gcc document on pre-processing](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Initial-processing.html) gives a pretty good rationale for a warning (*emphasis mine*):

> Trigraphs are not popular and many compilers implement them incorrectly. Portable code should not rely on trigraphs being either converted or ignored. With -Wtrigraphs GCC will warn you when **a trigraph may change the meaning of your program if it were converted**.

and in this gcc document [on Tokenization](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Tokenization.html) explains digraphs unlike trigraphs do not potential negative side effects (*emphasis mine*):

> There are **also six digraphs**, which the C++ standard calls alternative tokens, which are merely alternate ways to spell other punctuators. This is a second attempt to work around missing punctuation in obsolete systems. **It has no negative side effects, unlike trigraphs**,

Comment: This doesn't answer why digraphs *don't* throw a warning (or it would imply that they are more popular)

Comment: @schnaader that is the implication but I added another document to make that explicit

Comment: All three answers tell the same thing but I like yours as it includes short, correct quotes. The tick goes to you! :)

Answer (score 6):

Because trigraphs have the undesirable effect of *silently* changing code. This means that the same source file is valid both with and without trigraph replacement, but leads to *different* code. This is especially problematic in string literals, like `"<em>What??</em>"`.

Language design and language evolution should strive to avoid silent changes. Having the compiler warn about trigraphs is a good thing to have.

Contrast this with digraphs, which were *new tokens* that do not lead to silent changes.

Answer (score 4):

May be because it has no negative side effects, unlike trigraphs as is stated in [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Tokenization.html) documentation:

> Punctuators are all the usual bits of punctuation which are meaningful to C and C++. All but three of the punctuation characters in ASCII are C punctuators. The exceptions are ‘@’, ‘$’, and ‘`’. In addition, all the two- and three-character operators are punctuators. There are also six digraphs, which the C++ standard calls alternative tokens, which are merely alternate ways to spell other punctuators. This is a second attempt to work around missing punctuation in obsolete systems. It has no negative side effects, unlike trigraphs, but does not cover as much ground. The digraphs and their corresponding normal punctuators are:

```
 Digraph:        <%  %>  <:  :>  %:  %:%:
 Punctuator:      {   }   [   ]   #    ##
```

Answer (score 3):

Trigraphs are nasty because they use character sequences which could legally appear within valid code.  A common case which used to cause compiler errors on code for classic Macintosh:

```
unsigned int signature = '????';  /* Should be value 0x3F3F3F3F */
```

Trigraph processing would would turn that into:

```
unsigned int signature = '??^;  /* Should be value 0x3F3F3F3F */
```

which would of course not compile.  In some slightly rarer cases, it would be possible for such processing to yield code which would compile, but with different meaning from what was intended, e.g.

```
char *template = "????/1234";
```

which would get turned into

```
char *template = "??S4"; // ??/ becomes \, and \123 becomes S
```

Not the string literal that was intended, but still perfectly legitimate nonetheless.

By contrast, digraphs are relatively benign because outside of some possible weird corner cases involving macros, no code containing processable digraphs would have a legitimate meaning in the absence of such processing.