# <: cannot begin a template argument list

Tags: c++, parsing, templates, c-preprocessor, digraphs

I get an error <: cannot begin a template argument list on g++ compiler. Code

```
template<typename T> class SomeClass;
class Class;

SomeClass<::Class>* cls;
```

Comment: The new standrard (C++0x) addresses the issue of >> like in A<B<C>>. Doesn't it address this issue as well? Incidentally, Micorosoft compilers don't give error on this (I know that they technically should, but it's good they don't)

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan yes, this was fixed in C++0x which became C++11 although the fix for `>>` was done in section `14.3` which is different than the fix for `<::` which is a modification of the maximal much rule. So both annoying but different core issues at work. I detail this in my answer.

Answer (score 35):

According to the [Maximal Munch tokenization principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch) a valid C++ token must collect/have as many consecutive characters as possible.

`<:` is a [digraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs) (an alternative representation of symbol `[`).

```
                           Digraph  Equivalent
                              <:          [
                              :>          ]
                              <%          {
                              %>          }
                              %:          #
```

So `SomeClass<::Class>* cls;` is interpreted as `SomeClass[:Class>* cls;` which doesn't make any sense.

Solution: Add a whitespace between `<` and `:`

```
  SomeClass< ::Class>* cls;
            ^
            | 
           White Space
```

Answer (score 10):

Try the following instead:

```
SomeClass< ::Class>* cls;
```

You can find more info in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432443/why-are-there-digraphs-in-c-and-c) question about digraphs. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234582/purpose-of-trigraph-sequences-in-c) question about trigraphs could be helpful also.

Answer (score 7):

With C++11 the answer to this question changes a bit.

**Pre C++11**

Previous to C++11 the [maximal munch rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch) which is used in lexical analysis to avoid ambiguities and works by taking as many elements as it can to form a valid token caused this:

```
<::
```

to generate the following tokens as:

```
<: :
```

`<:` is a digraph which translates to `[` and so you end up with:

```
SomeClass[:Class>* cls;
```

which is not valid code.

We can confirm that this is the case by going to the draft C++ standard section `2.4` *Preprocessing tokens* which says:

> If the input stream has been parsed into preprocessing tokens up to a
>   given character, the next preprocessing token is the longest sequence
>   of characters that could constitute a preprocessing token, even if
>   that would cause further lexical analysis to fail.

and provides a couple of examples including the following classical maximal munch question:

> [ Example: The program fragment x+++++y is parsed as x ++ ++ + y,
>   which, if x and y are of built-in types, violates a constraint on
>   increment operators, even though the parse x ++ + ++ y might yield a
>   correct expression. —end example ]

**C++11**

In C++11 this changes, a rule was carved out for this case and the [draft C++11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) added the following:

> Otherwise, if the next three characters are <:: and the subsequent
>   character is neither : nor >, the < is treated as a preprocessor token
>   by itself and not as the first character of the alternative token <:.

to section `2.5` *Preprocessing tokens*. So this code will no longer produce and error in C++11.

This change came from [defect report: 1104](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3237.html)

Answer (score 1):

Put spaces around the < characters:

```
SomeClass < ::Class > * cls;
```

You only actually need to separate < and :, but I like symmetry.

Comment: plus one for liking symmetry