# Why does the template-id in "A<0>=0" not compile without space because of the greater-or-equal-than operator ">="?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, language-lawyer

```
template <int>
using A = int;

void f(A<0>=0);   // Attempting to declare a function f taking int,
                  // with the default argument 0

// Works as expected:
// void f(A<0> = 0);
```

This neither compiles on [GCC 4.9.2 nor Clang 3.5](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ca537ab1efae307e) - let alone ICC or VC++.  Apparently the `>=` bit is parsed as a greater-or-equal-than operator. However, this seems to be incorrect regarding [temp.names]/3:

> After name lookup (3.4) finds that a name is a *template-name* or that
>   an *operator-function-id* or a *literal-  operator-id* refers to a set
>   of overloaded functions any member of which is a function template, if
>   this is followed by a `<`, the `<` is always taken as the delimiter of
>   a *template-argument-list* and never as the less-than operator.
>   **When parsing a *template-argument-list*, the first non-nested
>   `>`<sup>138</sup> is taken as the ending delimiter** rather than a
>   greater-than operator. [..] [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> template<int i> class X { /* ...*/ };
>
> X< 1>2 > x1; // syntax error
> X<(1>2)> x2; // OK
> ```
>
> *— end example* ]
>
> <sup>138) A `>` that encloses the *type-id* of a `dynamic_cast`,
>   `static_cast`, `reinterpret_cast` or `const_cast`, or which encloses
>   the
>   *template-argument*s of a subsequent *template-id*, is considered nested for the purpose of this description.</sup>

Am I missing something or is this a compiler bug?

Comment: For reasons I do not understand at all, on gcc 4.7.3, the compile error is "too few arguments to function `void f(A<1>)`."

Comment: `>=` does not involve the greater-than operator.  It is the greater-than-or-equal operator, which is a different token.  Some efforts where made to make `foo< a<b>>` work (see the `>>` there?) to be treated like `foo< a<b> >`, but maybe  not for `>=`.  I'd start by figuring out where the changes to the standard that made `foo<a<b>>` work, and reverse engineer the problem from that?

Comment: Isn't this just the maximal much rule and this case needs a special exception like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24977313/1708801)

Comment: Yakk said it a bit, but when it's being parsed the compiler will read it as >=(because compilers are lazy) and because no one would necessarily think of the importance of adding a conditional to see if the > matches a < until a user(like you) reports it, and thus bugs would frequently occur. So yes __I__ would say it is a bug but other people may disagree.

Comment: This problem was actually noted in [N1757](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1757.html), the paper adding the special fix for `>>`.

Comment: @T.C. you now I read that last night before I went to sleep and I skipped right over that paragraph, otherwise I would have added it earlier.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This an effect of the [maximal munch principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch), which has the lexical analyzer take as many characters as possible to form a valid token. This is covered in draft C++ standard section `2.5` *[lex.pptoken]* which says:

> Otherwise, the next preprocessing token is the longest sequence of
>   characters that could constitute a preprocessing token, even if that
>   would cause further lexical analysis to fail.

Any cases such as the one you cite above need a specific exception carved out such as this case for `<::`, we can see an example in the following code:

```
template<typename T> class SomeClass;
class Class;

SomeClass<::Class>* cls;
```

which is covered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3952648/1708801), the exception is listed in the bullet just above the maximal munch rule:

> Otherwise, if the next three characters are <:: and the subsequent character is neither : nor >, the <
>   is treated as a preprocessor token by itself and not as the first character of the alternative token <:.

and of course the non-nested `>` which you cite in your question.

Note we can see that `>=` is a preprocessor token from section `2.13` *[lex.operators]* which says:

> The lexical representation of C++ programs includes a number of preprocessing tokens which are used in
>   the syntax of the preprocessor or are converted into tokens for operators and punctuators:

and includes `>=` in the list.

**The >> fix**

We can see from the proposal that fixed the `>>` case: [N1757: Right Angle Brackets](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1757.html) which says (*emphasis mine*):

> Ever since the introduction of angle brackets, C++ programmers have
>   been surprised by the fact that two consecutive right angle brackets
>   must be separated by whitespace:
>
> ```
> #include <vector>
> typedef std::vector<std::vector<int> > Table;  // OK
> typedef std::vector<std::vector<bool>> Flags;  // Error
> ```
>
> The problem is an **immediate consequence of the the “maximum munch”
>   principle** and the fact that >> is a valid token (right shift) in C++.
>
> This issue is a minor, but persisting, annoying, and somewhat
>   embarrassing problem. If the cost is reasonable, it seems therefore
>   worthwhile to eliminate the surprise.
>
> The purpose of this document is to explain ways to allow >> to be
>   treated as two closing angle brackets, as well as to discuss the
>   resulting issues. A specific option is proposed along with wording
>   that would implement the proposal in the current working paper.

Also points out the `>=` case:

> It is also worth noting that the problem can **also occur with the >>=
>   and >= tokens**. For example
>
> ```
> void func(List<B>= default_val1);
> void func(List<List<B>>= default_val2);
> ```
>
> Both of these forms are currently ill-formed. It may be desirable to
>   also address this issue, but this paper does not propose to do so.

Note, this change [broke backward compatibility with C++03](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23063914/1708801).