# Is there any example that triple colon (:::) is a valid syntax in c++ code?

Tags: c++, syntax

In my impression it seems I saw something like that:

```
A:::b()
```

But I don't remember if it is c++,also after searched "triple colon" in c++ but seems rare information about it in c++, is there any example that the code can have 3 colons(:::) in the code which is valid syntax?

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't a double colon? `A::b()` shows up pretty regularly

Answer (score 15):

This is slightly off topic because it refers to inline assembly rather than C++ per se. However, here's a tip for those who got here (as I did) after seeing this operator in the following expression:

```
asm volatile("" ::: "memory");
```

This syntax is used by gcc to tell the *compiler* to create a 'memory barrier'. Wikipedia's [Memory Ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_ordering#Compiler_memory_barrier) topic is a better explanation than I can provide.

Comment: If you are wondering about the syntax itself, check this https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html

Answer (score 5):

Given a global function `b`:

```
int b() {
    return 5;    
}
```

There are two (actually a couple more per Steephen's answer if you get creative<sup>1</sup>) cases where this would work, but only with a space:

1. As a label:

   ```
   int main() {
       A: ::b();
   }
   ```
2. As part of a conditional expression:

   ```
   int main() {
       int A = 0;
       int result = true ? A: ::b();
   }
   ```

The reason the space is needed is because C++ lexing is greedy and always lexes `:::` as `::` followed by `:`, never `:` followed by `::`. (A notable exception to this is `>>` being allowed to end two template parameter/argument lists only since a special change C++11.)

---

1: See examples of [access modifiers](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6de4ba22423cd2cf), [inheritance](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6853d065907f0b3f), [constructor initializer list](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96b1bc61bff8b649).

Comment: The [maximal munch principle](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28354898/1708801) which shows up in a bunch of places in C++.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there are valid C++ programs which include the sequence of characters `:::` (outside of comments and quoted literals).

Normally, that sequence would be lexically analysed as a `::` token (the scope resolution operator) followed by a `:` token. As far as I know, there is no valid C program of this form, because a `:` can only be preceded by a name (as a label) or an expression (either in a `case` label or as part of the ternary `?:` operator). And `::` cannot be the last token in an expression.

You can force the lexical analyser to produce a `:` followed by a `::` but only by placing whitespace between the two tokens, making `: ::`. And, of course, you can use the preprocessor to define a macro which ignores or stringifies an argument, so `:::` could appear as an argument to such a macro.

Leaving those aside, as far as I know the only possibility is when the first `:` is the second character in a `<:` token. For example:

```
const int size = 42;
int A<:::size:>;
```

([Live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dbbe36ea14602ecb).)

If that looks weird, remember that `<:` is an alternative spelling for `[` and `:>` is an alternative spelling for `]`. The unary scope resolution operator `::` indicates that the name it qualifies is in global scope.

Curiously, `<::` is an exception to the maximal-munch rule if it is *not* followed by `:` or `>`, in which case it must be analysed as `<` followed by `::` rather than as `<:` followed by `:`. However, when it is followed by `:` (as above) or `>`, maximal munch still applies and the first token is `<:`.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no triple colon(:::) as operator in C++

There is [scope resolution operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269034/what-is-the-meaning-of-prepended-double-colon-to-class-name), it is double colon(::).

There is single colon(:) that you can see along with access specifiers like private, public and protected. And also within [constructor syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor)