# How to use > (greater-than) inside a template parameter and not get a parsing error?

Tags: c++, parsing, templates

I want to only define a function based on the size of the template parameter:

```
template <class T>
typename std::enable_if<sizeof(T) > 1, void>::type
foobify(T v) {
    // ...
}

int main() {
    //foobify((unsigned char)30); // should not compile
    foobify((long)30);
}
```

However, I get:

```
main.cpp:8:41: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
     typename std::enable_if<sizeof(T) > 1, void>::type
```

It works if I instead do `1 < sizeof(T)`. Thus I believe GCC is thinking I am ending the template parameter, instead of continuing the boolean expression.

Is there any way to use `>` itself without having to work around it?

Comment: Also see [Operators and template-ids](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28354108/1708801)

Comment: You could also use `is_greater` `typename std::enable_if<std::isgreater(sizeof(T), 1), void>::type` :PPPPP

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes, expressions using that operator must be parenthesized. See [temp.names]/3:

> When parsing a *template-argument-list*, **the first non-nested `>`<sup>138</sup> is taken as the ending delimiter
>   rather than a greater-than operator.** [..] [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> template<int i> class X { /* ...*/ };
>
> X< 1>2 > x1; // syntax error
> X<(1>2)> x2; // OK
> ```
>
> *— end example* ]
>
> <sup>138) A `>` that encloses the *type-id* of a `dynamic_cast`, `static_cast`, `reinterpret_cast` or `const_cast`, or which encloses the
>   *template-argument*s of a subsequent *template-id*, is considered nested for the purpose of this description.</sup>

Clearly that doesn't apply if you use the symmetric counterpart of that comparison, i.e. employing `<`, instead - parsing is unambiguous in that case.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, you should use parentheses:

```
template <class T>
typename std::enable_if<(sizeof(T) > 1), void>::type
foobify(T v) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For C++20,

```
template<class T>
requires (sizeof(T) > 1)
void foobify(T v) {
    // ...
}

int main() {
//  foobify((unsigned char)30); // should not compile
    foobify((long)30);
}
```