# How can conditions on non-type template parameters be handled?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++17

An example given for non-type template parameters [is an array](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/template-non-type-parameters/):

```
template <typename T, int size> // size is an integral non-type parameter
class StaticArray
{
private:
    // The non-type parameter controls the size of the array
    T m_array[size] {};
}
```

What are the options for handling negative values in the input?  Using std::is_signed doesn't really apply - the template parameter is defined as signed, so the *type* would always be signed, whether or not the actual value provided is or not.

It looks like the implementation in std::array on my system sets the type to std::size_t, which isn't what I need in my use case.  I'm hoping for something I can use with std::enable_if, where negative values are valid but have different method implementations.

I've tried the following, but that the compiler doesn't seem to be sure how to distinguish the '>' operator vs '>' as a template indication.

```
template<>
Iterator& operator++(std::enable_if_t<SIZE > 0>) { m_ptr++; return *this; }  
template<>
Iterator& operator++(std::enable_if_t<SIZE < 0>) { m_ptr--; return *this; }
```

[edit]
I was unaware of `constexpr-if`, which seems like a better approach but is C++17 (my original tag was C++11, but I've now added C++17).

The following is at least compiling and seems more readable than conditionally added methods, but I'm not sure if this is the recommended approach:

```
Iterator& operator++()
{
    if constexpr (SIZE > 0)
        m_ptr++;
    else if constexpr (SIZE < 0)
        m_ptr--;
    else
        static_assert(SIZE == 0, "SIZE cannot be zero.");
    return *this;
}
```

[edit2]
The syntax for enable_if/enable_if_t is unclear to me for a non-type template parameter.  Both fail to compile when adding parentheses around the conditional.

With enable_if_t I get

```
error: argument may not have 'void' type
Iterator& operator++(std::enable_if_t<(SIZE > 0)>) { m_ptr++; return *this; }
                                                 ^
```

With enable_if, I get

```
error: parameter of overloaded post-increment operator must have type 'int' (not 'std::enable_if<(2 > 0)>')
Iterator& operator++(std::enable_if<(SIZE > 0)>) { m_ptr++; return *this; }
                                               ^
```

Comment: If you're getting an error, please include that message in the question. If there's no error, please include the behaviour of the code, and how it differs from what you expect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use > (greater-than) inside a template parameter and not get a parsing error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33423702/how-to-use-greater-than-inside-a-template-parameter-and-not-get-a-parsing-er)

Comment: Thanks @cigien, that addresses a part of my question.  I'm asking for the right approach, and getting my attempt to compile doesn't make it the right approach.  That question _did_ teach me something I didn't know, which is appreciated.  I'll edit my question.

Comment: Why the votes to close?

Comment: Why not just static_assert on `size > 0`? After all, `size` *cannot* change. It's a template parameter, and therefore is a constant expression. It's also not clear why you're focused on `operator++`, which again *cannot* change the size.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm trying to learn more about template programming and for my test use-case I'm trying to have different behavior for positive and negative values.  The only case which doesn't make sense is zero.  The idea is to have a class with an iterator that iterates forwards or backwards a set number of steps depending on the template parameter.  This helps with searching for a known pattern in potentially corrupted data.

Comment: @BrettStottlemyer: Your class declares an array with `size`. Arrays cannot have a size of 0 or of a negative number. So that's going to be a compile error *regardless* of what `operator++` eventually does.

Comment: @NicolBolas Sure.  My actual code is larger, with a complete Iterator struct with a class that takes a pointer.  I tried to make a minimal example that demonstrated the question, which is specific to the handling of the non-type template parameter.  Apologies if not including that detail impacted your understanding of the question.  I didn't know what direction this question would go!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example to get you started:

```
template <typename T, int size> // size is an integral non-type parameter
class StaticArray
{
private:
    T m_array[size] {};

public:
    std::enable_if_t<(size > 0), Iterator&>
    operator++() { /* ... */ }
};
```

Comment: Is the `Iterator &` supposed to be the return value for operator++ or part of the enable_if_t<>?  If the latter, what is that doing?

Comment: @BrettStottlemyer It's part of `enable_if_t<>`'s arguments; but `enable_if_t<>` is the expression deducing return type (when condition is true), so `Iterator&` is actually the return type _when_ this can be applied.

Comment: probably because size can never `<0` since it's array size. not my downvote though.

Comment: @appleapple Size can be `0`, then `(size > 0) == false`. Also, this code is from OP - they clearly wanted a condition there.

Comment: @lorro no, 0-size array is not allowed.

Comment: @appleapple `int size`, so technically it can be. It's not valid in generic C++ (in C99 it is valid), but most compilers support it. Even if it's not valid, it should be handled. Also, the idea is not to push whether it's `size == 0`, OP simply wanted a condition on a non-type parameter. If you look at OP's code, this condition is clearly there.

Comment: @lorro I'm not sure what your arguing, `size==0` is not valid, period. So the code is meaningless.

Comment: @lorro I'm just tell you what may be the reason you got that downvote. let me say it again, it's not mine.

Comment: @appleapple Understood, didn't mean to offend - just listing the reasons & logic behind it.