# Is this a bug in clang++/g++?

Tags: c++

Given:

```
void function(int*=0) {}
int main() {
}
```

clang (3.8.0):

```
test.cc:1:18: error: expected ')'
void function(int*=0) {
                 ^
```

g++ (5.4.0):

```
test.cc:1:18: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘*=’ token
 void function(int*=0) {
                  ^
```

If I change it to (note the spacing):

```
void function(int* = 0) {}
int main() {
}
```

Obviously it's getting confused whether I'm typing T* = 0 or T *= 0, is this a bug or expected?

Comment: Try naming your int* parameter and see if you still get an error.

Comment: This is due to maximal much see [Why doesn't a+++++b work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24947922/1708801) and the [more C++ specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28354108/1708801)

Comment: Looks like [maximal munch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch) to me.

Comment: You should add in a parameter name to add clarity.

Comment: I bet you get the same compiler error for `void function(int+=0)`

Comment: @ThomasMatthews This is ultimately derived from an SFINAE error for metaprogramming, so that parameter is never used.  If I gave it a name I'd get warnings about unused parameters too.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`*=`  is one operator, like `+=` is. So `x *= 2;`  is the same as `x = x * 2;`

You want `* =` to be lexed as two tokens (conceptually in C++, [lexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) happens *before*, and nearly independently, of [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing); read about C++ [translation phases](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases)).

Comment: but *= in this context makes completely no sense, why would compiler assume it is the multiply operator?

Comment: Because lexing & parsing are separate phases, conceptually

Comment: @bartop see [my comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50628782/is-this-a-bug-in-clang-g#comment88267705_50628782) wrt to maximal munch.

Comment: @bartop "_but *= in this context makes completely no sense_" True - it doesn't make sense, hence the reason why compiler complains about it. Tokenizer doesn't care about the context, it only cares about tokens, and `*=` is lexed as a single token.

Answer (score -2):

There is a short way to multiply a value, like:

```
foo *= 2;
```

Which basically does the same as:

```
foo = foo * 2;
```

Maybe that's what it is confused about.

Comment: That's not what's happening...

Comment: Enlighten us :)

Comment: Never mind -- I think I understand what you mean now. I didn't at first, sorry :-P