# Inconsistency parsing numeric literals according to C++ Standard's grammar

Tags: c++, syntax, c-preprocessor, language-lawyer, user-defined-literals

Reading through the C++17 standard, it seems to me that there is an inconsistency between *`pp-number`* as handled by the preprocessor and numeric literals, e.g. *`user-defined-integer-literal`*, as they are defined to be handled by the "upper" language.

For example, the following is correctly parsed as a *`pp-number`* according to the preprocessor grammar:

```
123_e+1
```

But placed in the context of a C++11-compliant code fragment,

```
int  operator"" _e(unsigned long long)
    { return 0; }

int test()
    {
    return 123_e+1;
    }
```

the current Clang or GCC compilers (I haven't tested others) will return an error similar to this:

```
unable to find numeric literal operator 'operator""_e+1'
```

where `operator"" _e(...)` is not found and trying to define `operator"" _e+1(...)` would be invalid.

It seems that this comes about because the compiler lexes the token as a *`pp-number`* first, but then fails to roll-back and apply the grammar rules for a *`user-defined-integer-literal`* when parsing the final expression.

In comparison, the following code compiles fine:

```
int  operator"" _d(unsigned long long)
    { return 0; }

int test()
    {
    return 0x123_d+1;  // doesn't lex as a 'pp-number' because 'sign' can only follow [eEpP]
    }
```

Is this a correct reading of the standard?  And if so, is it reasonable that the compiler should handle this, arguably rare, corner case?

Comment: For the note, MSVC compiles both cases fine.

Comment: There's no underscore allowed in [lex.ppnumber](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.ppnumber)! So parsing `123_e+1` as `pp-number` is wrong...

Comment: @Aconcagua - actually _`pp-number`_ lexes _`identifier-nondigit`_ and _`nondigit`_ includes underscore.

Comment: This isn't an answer because I'm not 100% sure that it's true for C++17, but similar corner cases exist in C and the interpretation is that the standard actually _requires_ it to be an error:  each pp-token is to be converted to one and only one phase-7 token, the compiler is not allowed to "roll back" as you put it.

Comment: @AndyG Oh, you seem to be right, sorry - but `+` is not covered? Interesting: p/P are included, but the 0x prefix isn't either...

Comment: My first instinct is that this is a [maximal munch case like >=](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28354898/1708801) and [a+++++b](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24947922/1708801) CC @zwol

Comment: @DeiDei MSVC is not correct on this one.

Comment: @Aconcagua `+` is covered by the `pp-number e sign` production, which is hard to spot at first and `0x` is covered by `pp-number identifier-nondigit`.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Hm, that would require to parse 1.e+E+p+P+e as `pp-number` as well... I'd say these construction rules are too generic then, next standard might (hopefully) get more precise (having two paths: allowing `e sign` only if not yet an identifier occured and vice versa)...

Comment: @Aconcagua it will be ill-formed at later stages, the grammar does not need to catch it here.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour If it would, we wouldn't need spaces, thus the `e` and `d` examples would not need to be treated differently. Interesting example, though, on how good formatting can prevent errors...

Comment: Interesting to note that a similar `123_p+1` has inconsistent treatment from clang and gcc [see it live](https://godbolt.org/z/3MsH9R) and using that example as opposed to the `_d` one and asking why clang and gcc has inconsistent results seems like a reasonable way to differentiate this and the duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have fallen victim to the [maximal munch rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_munch) which has the lexical analyzer take as many characters as possible to form a valid token.

This is covered in section [[lex.pptoken]p3](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.pptoken#3.3) which says (*emphasis mine*):

> Otherwise, the next preprocessing token is the longest sequence of characters that could constitute a preprocessing token, **even if that would cause further lexical analysis to fail**, except that a header-name ([lex.header]) is only formed within a #include directive.

and includes several examples:

> [ Example:
>
> ```
> #define R "x"
> const char* s = R"y";           // ill-formed raw string, not "x" "y"
> ```
>
> — end example ]
>
> 4 [ Example: The program fragment **0xe+foo is parsed
>   as a preprocessing number token (one that is not a valid floating or
>   integer literal token), even though a parse as three preprocessing
>   tokens 0xe, +, and foo might produce a valid expression (for example,
>   if foo were a macro defined as 1)**. Similarly, the program fragment 1E1
>   is parsed as a preprocessing number (one that is a valid floating
>   literal token), whether or not E is a macro name. — end example ]
>
> 5[ Example: The program fragment x+++++y is parsed as x ++ ++ + y,
>   which, if x and y have integral types, violates a constraint on
>   increment operators, even though the parse x ++ + ++ y might yield a
>   correct expression. — end example  ]

This rule effects in several other well known cases such as [a+++++b](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24947922/1708801) and [tokens  >= which required a fix to allow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28354898/1708801).

For reference the *pp-token* grammar is as follows:

> ```
> pp-number:  
>   digit  
>   . digit  
>   pp-number digit  
>   pp-number identifier-nondigit 
>   pp-number ' digit  
>   pp-number ' nondigit    
>   pp-number e sign  
>   pp-number E sign  
>   pp-number p sign  
>   pp-number P sign  
>   pp-number .
> ```

Note the `e sign` production, which is what is snagging this case. If on the other hand you use `d` like your second example you would not hit this ([see it live on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/yaLrCN)).

Also adding spacing would also fix your issue since you would no longer be subject to maximal munch ([see it live on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/UrezmJ)):

```
123_e + 1
```

Comment: Since you pinged me, again, I haven't close-read the C++ standard in many years and in particular I don't know if there are special rules for user-defined literals. This interpretation is correct for C provided you also take into account the usual interpretation of 5.1.1.2p1#7 "Each preprocessing token is converted into a token" meaning _one and only one_ token -- the compiler isn't supposed to split up a single pp-token into two phase 7 tokens, either, even when that would lead to a valid parse.

Comment: (Maximal munch _on phase 7 tokens_ would produce `0xe + foo` from example 4, because `0xe` is an integer-literal token and the production for integer-literals does not allow `+` at that point.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for the example from the standard.

Comment: @zwol Just following the parser rules, I think `0xe+foo` would need to be accepted as one token - as far as I understand (and learned...), interpreting the token as integer or FP literal is done at a later stage?

Comment: Now out of curiosity: How is the `x` in `0x` covered? Would it be treated as identifier-nondigit while parsing?

Comment: @Aconcagua I mean that's the whole question. `0xe+foo` is one _preprocessing_ token. The standard _could_ have been written to specify that lexical analysis is repeated after preprocessing, in which case the pp-token `0xe+foo` would become three phase 7 tokens, the integer-literal `0x3`, the operator `+`, and the identifier `foo`. The C standard wasn't written that way; instead it requires `0xe+foo` be converted to a _single_ phase 7 token, and there is no lexical production that matches, so it's a syntax error. I believe, but am not 100% sure, that the C++ standard is the same way.

Comment: @zwol: C++ is the same.

Comment: @rici Good to know, thanks.