# Why are there alternative tokens in C++?

Tags: c++, ansi-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are there digraphs in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432443/why-are-there-digraphs-in-c-and-c)
>   [What does the C ??!??! operator do?!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825055/what-does-the-c-operator-do)

In C++ there are alternative tokens for [] and {}, among others.

E.g. the following code compiles:

```
%:include <stdio.h>
int main() <%
    printf("Hello World!");
}
```

I thought about it for a while but couldn't figure any applicability, is there any logical reason for this?

Comment: Go find an old terminal keyboard :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're a hangover from C, really. There were implementations of C in which not all characters were available (such as some variants of EBCDIC that have no square brackets).

The C99 rationale document, section `5.2.1.1 Trigraph sequences` has this to say:

> Trigraph sequences were introduced in C89 as alternate spellings of some characters to allow the implementation of C in character sets which do not provide a sufficient number of non-alphabetic graphics.
>
> The characters in the ASCII repertoire used by C and absent from the ISO/IEC 646 invariant repertoire are `#`, `[`, `]`, `{`, `}`, `\`, `|`, `~`, and `^`

Comment: It was a problem with the keyboards actually, not the character set. I distinctly remember older Apples not having { and } keys.

Comment: @MrLister: Those were probably the same ones that lacked lower case (making writing C especially tricky).

Comment: @GregHewgill True; I wasn't trying to imply that C ran on Apple ][s anyway...

Comment: Actually, @MrLister, the C99 rationale states otherwise, it was specifically for the character set limitations of the ISO646 baseline. Apple's limitations may well have been severe - although no serious developer worked without the 80-column card, which gave you lowercase just fine. In any case, I remember using word processors on the II where inverse characters represented lowercase. That would be one ugly looking C program but it's doable.

Comment: @paxdiablo Ooh, those things were expensive. It took me years before I finally had one, because I really had to save up to buy a second floppy drive first.