# What is the meaning of char foo(|10|) in C?

Tags: c, mainframe, zos, ebcdic

I'm a very experienced C programmer, but recently I came across some code on a mainframe that has a local variable. This is in a simple C function that declares this variable, and then `strcpy` / `strcat`s two strings into it, and then tries an `fopen`.

```
char foo(|10|);
```

This code is very old.  Possibly even K&R C old.  I'm wondering if this is some obscure compiler extension or an adaptation to a keyboard that doesn't have [] or something like that.

Anyone know if this declaration is 'special'?

This is a standard Z/OS mainframe. I'm not sure what compiler is used.

Comment: It's an IBM mainframe... is it possible the character encoding is [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC)?  If Wikipedia is to be believed, it lacked the `[ ]` characters, so a C compiler meant to work on EBCDIC source may well have had to define some substitute.

Comment: ... though C defines trigraph sequences for exactly that purpose.  But perhaps that's a nonstandard / prestandard alternative.

Comment: @NateEldredge Could be, but that page also shows `|` as not necessarily present.

Comment: This question would be well-received on Retrocomputing.SE as well

Answer (score 108, accepted):

It seems to be an early or non-standard form of [digraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432443/why-are-there-digraphs-in-c-and-c).  The code was probably written using [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) instead of ASCII, and EBCDIC doesn't have `[ ]` characters (at least not in all code pages).

I found the [manual for SAS/C](https://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/ccompiler/doc650/clug.pdf), a C compiler apparently meant for System/370.  On page 2-10 (page 42 of the pdf) you can see they list `(| |)` as "alternate forms" for `[ ]`.

(Though apparently `|` is not in all the code pages either; but maybe it was in a code page that was more commonly used?  I don't know.)

C99 also included digraphs (and trigraphs) to solve the same problem, but they used `<: :>` as the digraphs, and `??( ??)` for the trigraphs.

Comment: This appears to be correct. A Google Books searched turned up a barely readable snippet of *Dr. Dobb's Journal* from 1993 that indicated that MVS EBCDIC didn't support `[` and `]` and the digraphs `(|` and `|)` were used instead.

Comment: Digraphs were added to standard C in C95 (ISO 9899/AMD1:1995).

Comment: Thanks -- this came out of an ebcdic character set mainframe.  I had heard of trigraphs (and checked!), but had never heard of digraphs in C code before!

Comment: Trigraphs were removed in the C++17 standard.  All the major compilers still have *optional* support for them, though.

Comment: But @dan04 this question is about the C language, not C++.